# Denovo, Stacks: Getting an “ambiguous redirect” error

Tags: snp, assembly, radseq

I tried running the following command

```
/public/home/WHC_BBT/Softwares/bin/bin/denovo_map.pl --samples $RawData -O $Popmap -o $fullM2n3 -M 2 -n 3 -m 3 -T 15 &> $logfile
```

This is the error I got

> /opt/gridview//pbs/dispatcher/mom_priv/jobs/14923.admin.SC: line 6:
> $logfile: ambiguous redirect

I need help on how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely means your variable `$logfile` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, the variable `$logfile` is not properly defined (i.e. it hasn't been defined at all). What is the output of the following command:

```
echo "logfile: ${logfile}"
```